# SpringData - CosmosDB - FluxUsingWhen cannot be cast to class Slice - Pagination

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-spring-boot

I am trying implement Pagination in cosmosdb as per the link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/spring-data-cosmos-readme?view=azure-java-stable#spring-data-custom-query-pageable-and-sorting) as follows.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCosmosRepository<User, String>{
    Slice<User> findByUserId(String userId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

POM.xml

```
...
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.7.13</version>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-data-cosmos</artifactId>
            <version>3.43.0</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

However, I'm getting the error on the method `findByUserId` as below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen cannot be cast to class org.springframework.data.domain.Slice (reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen and org.springframework.data.domain.Slice are in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @37c9dbe)
[2024-03-06T15:45:45.536Z]  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.findByUserId(Unknown Source)
[2024-03-06T15:45:45.536Z]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Any help?